# IntelliJ Error Loading Project: Cannot load modules

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

After deleting several modules from a Maven project in IntelliJ Idea, I'm getting the following message when opening the project

```
Error Loading Project: Cannot load 4 modules.
```

However, there are no `iml` files of the deleted modules of any other information left from them. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you copy the modules to a new project folder and recreate the project? Otherwise go in "project structure" -> "modules" and see if anything is red?

Comment: @vikingsteve deleted modules don't exist anymore and I don't need them in a project. Nothing is in red in "modules".

Comment: Are the modules you deleted in "modules", or are they gone? Anything extra there that can be deleted?

Comment: It could be that they are still referenced in the modules.xml in the .idea folder. Have you tried deleting all .iml files and the .idea folder and then opening the project again?